# Converting PWA to iOS app with PWABuilder and WebRTC camera/microphone support

Tags: ios, webrtc, progressive-web-apps, pwabuilder

I need your help guys

Hello,

I’m in the process of converting a Progressive Web App (PWA) to a standalone iOS app using PWABuilder. The PWA makes use of WebRTC features, specifically the camera and microphone, for real-time communication.

I would like to know if anyone has experience using PWABuilder to convert a PWA that relies on WebRTC camera and microphone functionalities into a native iOS app successfully.

I have a few specific questions:

Does PWABuilder handle the conversion process of WebRTC features, such as camera and microphone, correctly when generating the iOS app package?

Are there any known limitations or issues when converting a PWA with WebRTC capabilities to an iOS app using PWABuilder?

Are there any additional steps or considerations I need to keep in mind to ensure that the camera and microphone functionalities work properly in the converted iOS app?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, best practices, or personal experiences related to this topic. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my experience related to this topic. I created an iOS app using PWABuilder and submitted to app review. It was rejected because the app requested to access camera and microphone, but the explanation in the purpose string was insufficient.

I can see the following lines in `Entitlements.plist` file which was generated by PWABuilder.

```
<key>com.apple.security.device.audio-input</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.device.camera</key>
<true/>
```

In my case, I'm trying to remove the access request because my app doesn't need camera and microphone.